# Standard iMac pmset

Tags: imac, sleep-wake, macos

I recently got a new iMac 5k late 2015 with 2Tb Fusion drive. Ever since arrival, it had sleep problems. It would go to sleep and wake without any problems except if it went into standby(after 3 hours of sleep). When waking the screen was black  with some red graphics glitch on top where the menu bar is, it would go to a login screen only if i kept pressing different keys. After fiddling in the terminal I saw that in `pmset -g` standby was 1, so I removed standby like so `sudo pmset -a standby 0`

Now all seems ok.

*My question is, do iMacs need to have `standby 0` by default and mine was activated by mistake or does it have a hardware fault that should be checked ASAP?*

I checked another iMac and saw that it had `standby 0` as well. I don't know what to believe.

This is my `pmset -g`:

```
standby              0
Sleep On Power Button 1
womp                 1
halfdim              1
hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
powernap             1
autorestart          0
networkoversleep     0
disksleep            1
sleep                10 (sleep prevented by Google Chrome, coreaudiod)
autopoweroffdelay    28800
hibernatemode        3
autopoweroff         1
ttyskeepawake        1
displaysleep         10
standbydelay         10800
```

Activated hibernatemode 3 just in case power went off when it's in sleep.